# Is it possible to have thin lines or crop marks to help cut the pages with \setuparranging?

Tags: context, crop, context-mkiv

I have something like this:

```
\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]
\setuppapersize[A5,landscape][A4]
\setuplayout[topspace=1cm,backspace=1cm,
  header=0mm,footer=0mm,
  width=middle,height=middle]
\setuparranging[2TOP]
```

I'd like to have a thin line in the middle of the page so that I know where to cut the paper.  Alternatively, kind of "crop marks" with the same purpose would do.  Is there an option for that?  `marking=on` in `\setuplayout` didn't help (probably because the "classical" crop marks fall outside of the paper with these settings - am I right?).

I'm using ConTeXt MkIV.

*Note: please retag this question as appropriate, I didn't know what tags would be best.*

Answer (score 8):

Marking are usually shown in a way so that they do no show when the page is cut. One way to see what is happening is to set the print paer size to A3. For example,

```
\setuppapersize[A5,landscape][A3]
\setuparranging[2TOP]

\setuplayout
  [
    topspace=1cm,
    backspace=1cm,
    header=0mm,
    footer=0mm,
    width=middle,
    height=middle,
    marking=on,
    location=middle,
  ]

  \showframe
```

[image]

However, you can easily add a background image to show your own marks.

```
\setuppapersize[A5,landscape][A4]
\setuparranging[2TOP]

\setuplayout
  [
    topspace=1cm,
    backspace=1cm,
    header=0mm,
    footer=0mm,
    width=middle,
    height=middle,
    marking=on,
    location=middle,
  ]

\startuseMPgraphic{cropmarks}
  StartPage;
  begingroup;
  drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1bp withcolor red);
  if odd(\the\realpageno) :
    draw (0,0) -- (1cm, 0);
    draw (PaperWidth,1mm) -- (PaperWidth-1cm, 1mm);
  fi ;
  endgroup;
  StopPage;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[cropmarks][\useMPgraphic{cropmarks}]

\setupbackgrounds[page][background=cropmarks]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same idea as Aditya, however with a different approach. Adityas solution resorts to MetaPost, the most flexible solution you can get. The following solution uses a version of ConTeXts `\framed` command to draw a thin line between the pages without direct use of MetaPost.

```
\setuppagenumbering [state=stop]
\setuparranging     [2TOP]
\setuppapersize     [A5,landscape] [A4]
\setuplayout
  [
     topspace=1cm,
    backspace=1cm,
       header=0mm,
       footer=0mm,
        width=middle,
       height=middle,
  ]

\setupbackgrounds [page] [background=cropmarks, setups=cropmarks]
\definelayer      [cropmarks]

\startsetups cropmarks
  \doifoddpageelse{}{%
    \setlayerframed [cropmarks]
      [
           frame=off,
        topframe=on,
           width=\paperwidth,
          height=\paperheight,
      ]{}}
\stopsetups

\starttext
  \dorecurse{20}{
    \input knuth\par}
\stoptext
```

The result:

[image: result]

**EDIT:** The code above is way too complicated, much easier:

```
\setuppagenumbering [state=stop]
\setuparranging     [2TOP]
\setuppapersize     [A5,landscape] [A4]
\setupbackgrounds   [page] [topframe=on]
\setuplayout
  [  topspace=1cm,
    backspace=1cm,
       header=0mm,
       footer=0mm,
        width=middle,
       height=middle]

\starttext
  \dorecurse{20}{
    \input knuth\par}
\stoptext
```

Comment: It is better to use `\doifoddpageelse{...}{...}` rather an an explicit `\ifodd...` test.

Comment: You're totally right, I changed it. The point is that it's easy to remember the basic TeX building blocks. ConTeXt has so many of them, I have to look them up. And, you know … the human in general is lazy :)